# How to make an email template for gmail using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, html-email

I was wondering how I could design an email template using HTML and CSS and then incorporate that into an email. I want to do it as other companies do when they send confirmation emails and newsletters.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on [webapps.se]

Comment: Most known mailchimp.com

Answer (score 7):

Whether you prefer to code an email by hand, or use a pre-existing template, there are a few rules to keep in mind in creating an HTML email:

- Utilize Tables in your Layouts
- Fixed-Width Positioning (for non-responsive emails)
- Pixel Units
- The Possibilities with CSS (check Ultimate Guide to CSS link below)
- Inline CSS
- Anchor Links Best Practices
- Test in All Major Clients
- Always Offer Web-Based Views
- Adding Image Content
- Avoid the Spam Folder!
- Add Un-Subscribe Option

Take a look at these sites for more info on this subject:

[How to Code HTML Email Newsletters](http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/)

[9 Tricks to Design The Perfect HTML Newsletter](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/design-perfect-newsletter/)

[How To Code An Email Newsletter in 6 Simple Steps](http://blog.crazyegg.com/2012/05/14/how-to-code-an-email-newsletter/)

[The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) - A complete breakdown of the CSS support for every popular mobile, web and desktop email client

Answer (score 5):

A very useful book that I used before I start a job is:

[Modern HTML Email - Jason Rodriguez](http://modernhtmlemail.com/)

There are very few books on writing HTML for email, so this is one of the only decent ones I found!

Whenever I start making an email, I use a starting point such as this below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;}
.ReadMsgBody{width:100%;}
.ExternalClass{width:100%;}
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
</style>
</head>

<body style="padding:0px; margin:0PX;" bgcolor="">
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor=""  style="table-layout:fixed; margin:0 auto;">
<tr>
<td width="640" align="center" valign="top">

<!--Insert content here-->


</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This includes some fixes, such as a 100% wrapping table on the outside which means that Yahoo! Will not left align your email and a fix for the line-height issue in Outlook.com, where Outlook.com makes all line-heights 131%. The width included in here is 640, which gives the email a fixed width for desktop and is normally 600-700px.

Tables should be used at all times, and tables contain rows and columns (`<tr>` and `<td>`). Tables can be nested within eachother:

```
<table width="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Each row within a table needs to have the same number of columns, otherwise columns within a row will need to be nested within a table. Tables can also be stacked, so within a `<td>`, you can have multiple tables that will stack vertically without the need of rows. The content, such as text, or images goes within a `<td>`.

All CSS styling should be inline:

```
<td align="right" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height:14px; color:#fffffe; text-align:right; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal;">Hello</td>
```